# svn revision number set by propset doesn't match

Tags: svn, revision

I added the $Rev$ tag and invoked svn propset on a set of files during my project. The revision number that shows up is $Rev: 8 $ but during checkout it says I am on Revision 10. I think the $Rev$ counter does not reflect the actual revision number but the revision since svn propset was invoked? Anyone know how I can I sync the two?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Misunderstanding on subversion.  The version on a file in subversion is the last subversion that it was changed in.  THe checkout revision is basically: "check out the most recent version of every file that is less than (*EDIT** or equal to) 10".

* Should slap myself as a professional programmer for getting that one wrong.

Comment: +1, but I had to look at your edit history to understand what you were saying, lol. Just rollback if you don't agree with the changes.

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry, that's a common misunderstanding for new players with Subversion.

As explained by Spence, file revision != checkout revision

`$Rev$` = file revision

Revision displayed during checkout = checkout revision